# Ask for question undeletion with less than 10k reputation

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-undelete, undeleted-questions

There was a question that was asked very poorly, but what was being asked was actually not that dumb.

I have a good answer for it, but the question got deleted.

Assuming that it wasn't deleted by OP and that I have less than 10k reputation, is there a mechanism in place to request the question to be undeleted?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What was the question? (Link please)

Comment: I don't know why the downvote was cast, but one possible explanation is your apparent lack of concern with fixing the *question* once it gets undeleted, which is really the most important thing to prevent it from getting deleted *again*. That you have a good answer isn't going to be enough to warrant undeletion. Are you going to fix it?

Comment: @Cerbrus, I actually realized that it was deleted by OP so this meta question is more like a general question rather than a support request for this specific instance.

Comment: @Pekka웃, of course I would have suggested to the OP to change the question in a way that my answer is correct. :)

Comment: If you don't have access to the question, then you only have two options: bring it up here on Meta, or flag another of the OP's questions and explain that you think another of theirs has been wrongly deleted. I would suggest that the former is better, as the moderators have plenty on already and (unless you don't have a link to the deleted question, in which case we may need them to find it) it can be dealt with by the community.

Comment: Consider finding a duplicate of that question to *maybe* answer, or if none exists to post a self-answered question... Keep in mind both Q and A have to be acceptable quality though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that question is still good enough to be salvageable in a way that can be explained to others you can always hop into the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room. That chat room has enough regulars around that have the experience, judgement and reputation requirement to help out in such cases.

Keep in mind though that you'll need to provide a link to the question because we have no ways to search in deleted content. It might be worth to try to contact the OP before you request undeletion as they might have valid reasons to delete their question.

Also after deletion  make sure you work with the OP to get the question in to shape so your answer will be value not only to the OP but to future visitors as well.